# How to store a nested ArrayList in a JsonObject

Tags: java, json, arraylist

So I have this ArrayList existing of school classes and each class has an ArrayList containing ArrayLists of additional values. I would have to declare it like this

`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

I'll be looping through this rota of classes and will add this in a JsonObject using the JsonObjectBuilder. Here's an example.

```
JsonArrayBuilder arrBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (Rota class : rotaArray) {
  JsonObjectBuilder builderRota = Json.createObjectBuilder();
  String example = class.getExample();
  //This is where I get the ArrayList of each class.
  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrExample = class.getArrExample();
  builderRota
      .add("example", example)
      //This is where I'm stuck since the builder expects it to have a String as value instead of an ArrayList.
      .add("arr", arrExample);
   arrBuilder.add(builderRota);
}
```

Now, how would I go about storing that ArrayList in the JsonObject so that I can use this later on? (I'll be retrieving this JsonObject with Polymer, but being able to store the array first would be the first step.

Thank in advance!

Comment: what is your end goal? I assume you want to convert `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to json and potentially read it back later ?

Comment: @Raj My end goal is to read it back later in Polymer as a json object or something that's readable by JS. I've tried simply to put toString() behind arrExample, but this would return a string like this [[string, 1, string], [string, 2, string]] in Polymer using the data binding. I can't parse this string with JSON.parse() either because the strings have no double quotes otherwise I probably would've worked something out but i'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jackson library to do this easily. That library will not need you to mess around with Json* classes that you have right now. Try this -

```
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
public void testJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> input = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
        input.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(2*i),String.valueOf(3*i))));
    }

    // This converts the Array to Json
    // This class is part of jackson library - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input));
}
```

For me, it printed `[["2","3"],["4","6"],["6","9"],["8","12"],["10","15"],["12","18"],["14","21"],["16","24"],["18","27"],["20","30"]]`